# Subregularities and irregularities

Tags: terminology

It seems that some syntacticians sometimes use the word subregularity instead of irregularity. Is there any difference between these two terms or they cover same concept?

Comment: Another term that has been used sometimes seems to be "[quasi-regularity](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/000344.html)"

Comment: What would you call the obvious but limited-scope pattern one finds in, for example, the class of zero-suffix monosyllabic dental-stop-final verbs that includes _bet
bid
burst
cast
cost
cut
fit
hit
hurt
let
put
quit
rid
set
shed
shit
shut
slit
spit
split
spread
thrust_? Me, I'd call it a subregularity. There are dozens more in English verb classes alone. In one sense, it could be thought of as an irregularity (no suffixes, after all), but it's certainly governed by rule. Just not very widely applicable rules.